# My Macbook Pro display is not showing anything

Tags: macbook

My macbook pro is currently connected to an LCD monitor and the display is mirrored across the laptop's monitor and the LCD.  However, the display on my laptop is not working anymore, but I can see still use my LCD to work.  Does anyone know how I can turn my laptop monitor back on?  Did I push some keys by accident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have dimmed it all the way down.  Seen it plenty of times.  Look for the brightness keys up on the F-key level.  Mine are F1 (dim) and F2 (brighten).